# Direct update of app in worklight 6.1 not working

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I have an ios app that is not getting updated when a new wlapp file is uploaded into the server.  There is one developer who has a workspace that is generating the ipa file.  We have an ant script that runs on a different server to build the wlapp file.  We've verified that they are at the same level of worklight, 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356.  The server has 6.1 installed on it.  The only way I've been able to get the update to work is if I build from the same physical machine everytime the wlapp and ipa file on a test system I have.  Any help will be greatly welcomed.

Update:
still researching.  I've found that on a different server, on the WL.Client.connect call, the following json comes back as part of the response

```
gadgetProps":{"directUpdate":{"updateUnpackedSize":5545609,"availableSkins":["default"],"checksum":186203335,"updateSize":2105359},"ENVIRONMENT":"iphone"}
```

On the servers where it is failing the same scenario returns the following in the connect call

```
gadgetProps":{"directUpdate":{},"ENVIRONMENT":"iphone"}
```

Comment: Verify the wlapp is generated with correct server URL; also what do the logs say in the server?

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the logs and didn't see anything that jumped out.  I could see where we would deploy a new wlapp file but no entries for when it was sending back the gadget information.  We verified the server level and found that server was at  6.1.0.00.20131126-0630. FP1 of the WL Server had the following fixed defects lists.

- PI06652 DIRECT UPDATE ALLOWS USERS TO KEEP USING OUTDATED VERSIONS
- PI06943 DIRECT UPDATE NOTIFICATION WHEN NONE IS AVAILABLE, THEN FAILS UPON AN UPDATE ATTEMPT

We tried on a different server that has the FP1 applied and we were able to see the direct update information and process work.

Comment: Are you using the latest worklight-ant.jar file for ANT build script?